# [Grails/Groovy]minimum value of Map entries

Tags: grails, groovy

Query: how can i pull minimum value from a map in Grails

So far i have found following code to get minimum value from a map in groovy

```
["Java":1, "Groovy":4, "JavaScript":2].min{it.value}
```

but it donot work in Grails

i have tried following piece of code

```
def map = ["Java":1, "Groovy":4, "JavaScript":2]
println map.min{it.value}
assert map.min{it.value}==1
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the minimum value from the map, you can do:

```
def map = ["Java":1, "Groovy":4, "JavaScript":2]
println map.values().min()
assert map.values().min() == 1
```

**edit**

Also, the [closure accepting version of `map.min`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#min%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) has been in Groovy since 1.7.6, and Grails (as of v1.3.6) uses Groovy 1.7.5

Comment: would you mind to describing little bit why groovy code,[code]map.min{it.value}[/code], isnt working in Grails ?  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`min()` doesn't return a minimum value returned by argument closure, it returns the element of a collection for which the closure returns minimum.

`map.min {it.value}` is valid call, but it's not a value. It's a `MapEntry`, with `key` and `value` properties. So `map.min{it.value}.value` would do.

Comment: Thanks for reply. `map.min{it.value}` ends up with following error `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap.min() is applicable for argument types: (`. Ive also tried  `map.min{it.value}.value` . Any suggestions ?

Comment: i think it all depend upon Grails version, currently i m using 1.3.6, and there i have found that groovy version is 1.7.5. And ´min´ function need to have groovy version 1.7.6.